# Can't specify specific tag using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

i=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/text()[1]')
```

I then get the error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid
> selector: The result of the xpath expression
> "//*[@id="watchListPage"]/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/text()[54]" is:
> [object Text]. It should be an element.

If I remove the `/text()[1]` it works fine but I need to specify what line I want it to read.

the html looks something like this

div class="spoiler-body" style="display: block;">

br>

br>

Title

br>

br>

Text

br>

br>

Changes

br>

br>

WEEKLY........      0 |  3.314% |  320412 | 0.67% |

br>

MONTHLY.......      0 |  23.58% |  253268 |  11.58% |

br>

QUARTERLY.....      0 |  40.94% |  252030 |  11.61% |

br>

YEARLY........      0 |  19.2% |  186700 |  14.52% |

div>

I want to be able to select one of those lines of text specifically

can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try using xpath finder extensions in your broser to find the xpath ? Also you could include the website and the element you want to find in the question.

Comment: Why not just use i.text  while removing /text()[54]  and parse that.

Answer (score 0):

Hey don't copy the xpath, copy the full xpath.
For example, Let's inspect the heading of your own(this) stackoverflow question:

- The xpath of your question title is : `//*[@id="question-header"]/h1/a`
- **But** full xpath of this question's title is: `/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/h1/a`

So you need to copy full xpath instead of only xpath, as although it is `find_element_by_xpath()` but it needs full xpath!